# Android build variant debug gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, smack

I have been working on a project that has been perfectly fine, until i included the android-smack-xmpp library.

After this inclusion, i am not able to run the app on devices (API < 21) on debug mode. However i am able to run it on release build variant.

```
                                                             Process: com.example, PID: 496


                                                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.network.ServerCalls$3
                                                                 at com.example.network.ServerCalls.initData(ServerCalls.java:167)
                                                                 at com.example.ui.fragmentsAndActivities.homeFeed.HomePageActivity.onCreate(HomePageActivity.java:212)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ServerCalls is included in the HomePageActivity, and compilation works just fine. What is that i could be missing here ?

Also HomePageActivity.java:212 is :

```
ServerCalls.samosaInitData()
```

Edit : I have been able to get it working my setting `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to `true` in gradle for the debug build. This is probably pointing at improper linking in the JVM. But this looks like a hack to me. Can somebody point me to a cleaner way of doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was multi-dexing the solution.
The smack-api library introduction led to the 64k dex limit to be exceeded. 
Multidexing the solution does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't export your library in the final .apk file.

[image]

You have to choose the Compile option in your Android Studio project settings in the Dependencies section.

Comment: I have set the smack api is set to compile. the class 'ServerCalls' is in the main project itself, though.